# How to access spaced string of value attribute in Behat?

Tags: php, testing, automation, behat, mink

I am not able to click on submit button. I have html as shown below.

```
`<input id="edit-submit" class="form-submit" type="submit" value="Achteraf betalen" name="submit" onclick="return validate_step3();">` <br>
```

I am using the iPress function as shown below in features.php file. I tried with iClick(), iClickElementWithId() But not able click at all.

```
/**
 * @Given /^I Press "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iPress($value)
{
    $val="$value";
    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
    $element = $page->find('css',"input[value=$val]");
    $element->doubleClick();
}
```

I am getting the below error message while executing.

> And I Press "Achteraf betalen"   Expected "]", but  found.

So, please give some suggestions.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `$page->find()` call. Enclose the value in quotes:

```
$element = $page->find('css',"input[value='$val']");
```

Comment: Thank you.. But while storing the parameter in the $val variable, we are keeping inside double quotes. Is this required here also??

Comment: The line `$val="$value";` only assigns $value to $val, the double quotes simple do nothing. You could as well omit the line and use $value directly.

Comment: In contrast of that, in the $page->find() call the double quotes are necessary. They make it possible to use variables inside the string. This mechanism is called "interpolation". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation